# Ending Support for Older Android Versions in My App's Free and Paid Versions on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, software-distribution, android-version

I'm considering ending support for older Android versions of my app, which is available in both free and paid versions on the Google Play Store. This decision is motivated by the technical and maintenance challenges of supporting older versions of Android.

I need advice on managing this transition for both the free and paid versions, especially regarding my obligations to paid users.

1. How can I discontinue support while minimizing disruption for users, and what are the best practices for communicating these changes?
2. Are there any legal considerations, particularly for those who have purchased the paid version?

I would greatly appreciate insights or experiences from others who have faced similar situations.